# There is no Use Gravity property in Rigidbody2D

Tags: unity-game-engine

There is no **Use Gravity** property in Rigidbody2D. How can I handle gravity in 2D?

Answer (score 9):

A RigidBody2D has a [gravityScale](https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D-gravityScale.html). It is this gravity scale with which you can adjust how much effect gravity has on the particular object. Setting it to 0 would have the same effect as turning off gravity for a RigidBody.